# Squeeze first dimension if it is equal to 1 using tf.cond

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor `a` and I would like to squeeze its first dimension if it is equal to 1.

I tried

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.zeros((2, 3))
tf.cond(tf.equal(a.shape[0], 1), lambda: tf.squeeze(a, axis=0), lambda: a)
```

but it does not work because `tf.cond` executes both `true_fn` and `false_fn` before the condition is evaluated thus yielding an error if `a`'s first dimension is not `1`:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 2 for 'cond/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [2,3].
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
dims = tf.cond(tf.equal(a.shape[0], 1), lambda: tf.shape(a)[1:], lambda: tf.shape(a))
reshaped = tf.reshape(a, dims)
```

Instead of squeezing, I am getting the shape of `a` in `tf.cond`, where if the first axis is `1`, I will get the shape without the first axis or the full shape otherwise. Then, I just reshape `a` to the obtained shape.

Answer (score 1):

Could you maybe use

```
tf.cond(tf.equal(a.shape[0], 1), lambda: a[0], lambda: a)
```

Instead of squeezing, we simply index into the first dimension and grab the only entry there. This can probably still crash in certain situations but it should work around your specific issue.

Comment: This definitely circumvents the sanity check TensorFlow does with tf.squeeze.